# Translate to PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform

What is the equivalent of this code in PHP:

```
  curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 4zcn5cCjKV8zYqoaHcasKFyUBxPB2qP7NYOZhMnw" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: GHHLNoICIZFXkD59QAwbDRVUd4JeSU4hVpBFq2md" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":73453}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

**EDIT:**

```
                        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' . $table_name . '/Jwqe23ls'; 
                        $headers = array(   "Content-Type: application/json",  
                                            "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
                                            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey,
                                            "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" );  
                        $objectData = '{"number":"4"}';
                        $rest = curl_init();  
                        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);                
                        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $objectData);  
                        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
                        curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
                        $response = curl_exec($rest);  
                        echo $response;
                        curl_close($rest);
```

Now it works...

Answer (score 0):

If you want `PUT`, do it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

Also, it seems to me that `score:73453` is different from `number:4`, but that's probably not important at this stage.

Comment: Yes, that's not important. Now I get: {"code":107,"error":"invalid json: "}

Comment: In that case, it might be important. That message seems to indicate that the request in itself is okay, but the API has trouble interpreting your json. That might be because it is not well-formatted, but maybe also because it doesn't contain the right fields, or it is sent in the wrong encoding.

Comment: Look at my edit. For some reason it works now, but didn't work with CURLOPT_PUT...

Comment: Weird. Using CURLOPT_PUT is the proper way to do it. But what you did works as well: basically add the header yourself. There shouldn't be any difference in behaviour, but oh well..